# grabbing text between all tags in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

what would be the most efficient way of grabbing all texts between html tags ?

```
<div>
<a> hi </a>
....
```

bunch of texts surrounded by html tags.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize too

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html)
doc.xpath("//text()").to_s
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a Sax parser.  Much faster than the XPath option.

```
require "nokogiri"

some_html = <<-HTML
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is the body!
  </body>
</html>
HTML

class TextHandler < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def initialize
    @chunks = []
  end

  attr_reader :chunks

  def cdata_block(string)
    characters(string)
  end

  def characters(string)
    @chunks << string.strip if string.strip != ""
  end
end
th = TextHandler.new
parser = Nokogiri::HTML::SAX::Parser.new(th)
parser.parse(some_html)
puts th.chunks.inspect
```

Comment: how could this be changed to only get text between body tag alone?

Comment: Set a flag and only begin capturing characters after you see the body tag begin and stop capturing after the body tag closes.

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html)
doc.xpath("//text()").text
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get all the text in the question div of this page:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512850/grabbing-text-between-all-tags-in-nokogiri"))
puts doc.css("#question").to_s
```